# ASP Webforms or MVC for a Complex Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have read just about every question/answers about webforms vs MVC. But none has addressed what I am about to ask.

We are a small development team (3 ppl) and we have a legacy application similar to Crystal Reports.

We need to convert this VB6 app to a web based app. Reason? It was written in VB6 and support for VB6 will be phased out in Windows 8. This application is / will be similar to Crystal Reports / Google Docs where thousands of users will use the web app to generate complex reports from a large database. Charts and graphs will be generated dynamically based on the data queried. All reports can then be exported to PDF and other supported document file types. Possible feature is creating Word documents with this data or at least annotating the PDF reports. Document/Content Management back end also required for storage and searching.

OK - so clearly its a rather complicated web application with loads of database access/queries. The front end will also need to be rather spick (although gridviews not compulsory).

Constraints:
1. Time to market is relatively short (6months to 1 year)

1. Technology should last or be available for the next 10-20 years - We can't work on this application forever, having to constantly updating and re-writing it every time new technology supersedes older technology. HTML will last beyond this time, but will ASP.NET?
2. User end performance needs to be relatively quick. it doesn't have to be blistering quick; but it shouldn't lag so much (more than 2 seconds for response) that users begin to complain. (ie ViewState not a prob if it doesn't exceed 100Kb).

Please answer my questions:

1. So my question to you is: do we go with Webforms or MVC?
2. MVC sounds attractive but MVC is STATELESS. Do you think this application will need to keep state or can I do without it? Or is it possible to implement state in MVC (confused)?
3. Some users are in govt departments and have have laptops that a clamped down for security reasons (by their IT Admin) - so Javascript, for a significant number of users will be TURNED OFF. This means JQuery may not be possible technology. Is there some way to accommodate for Javascript and non Javascript browsers?

Thanks in advance.

Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Web Forms**.

Here's why:

1 - Faster development time (rapid application development) - as stated in your time constraint

2 - For complex charts/reports/grids, you'd have to roll your own with ASP.NET MVC (or use a helper someone else has created). But with Web Forms you have a wealth of server controls (and products like Telerik).

So do answer your questions:

1. Web Forms - see above.
2. We can't answer that - we don't know how exactly your application will operate. MVC is not stateless per-se, it is stateless in that it doesn't use ViewState. But you can still use things like Session.
3. JavaScript is client-side, and has no bearing on Web Forms vs MVC. You'll have to cater for scenarios with no JavaScript (minimize AJAX work, effects, etc).

You've mentioned "speed needs to be quick". Well if ViewState is a problem, then turn it off! It annoys me people who say "I hate ViewState, it makes pages slow", when you can simply turn it off at the control or page level.

BTW - i am by no means a Web Forms advocate - i actually prefer ASP.NET MVC. But from what i've read in your question, i would go with Web Forms.

Comment: As a fellow MVC advocate, I agree with your answer.

Comment: Yup. The only two areas (IMO) Web Forms has over MVC is RAD and complex server controls - both of which he requires.

Comment: Malarkey.  The RAD in webforms comes from being able to drag a SqlDataSource and a GridView on a page. In that case I can simply right click and say "add view for model" and do almost the same with MVC.   RAD WebForms is a monstrosity of bad coding practices.  So yeah, you develop slightly faster but you sacrifice any sort of maintainability.  Any time you start doing Object.FirstName = firstName.Text or OnItemDataBound nonsense you lose.   The WebForms = RAD is a myth

Comment: You take two teams, one with WebForms and the other with MVC and the time you spend with WebForms figuring out some Telerik monstrosity and working out control trees and UpdatePanel madness is the same time I can write reusable and clean UI and HtmlHelpers that can be used on the next project.  At the end we may finish on time, starting from scratch, but I'll have clean code with separations of concerns that is just waiting to be unit tested.  And don't get me started on the difference between MVC AJAX with JQuery and UpdatePanel.

Comment: PDFs and Word docs are just as easy or easier with MVC as well.  FileResult is golden for this type of thing.  Take any PDF or Word library and your good to go.

Comment: Thank for your replies. Webforms was my initial thought as well. Only problem is that MVC 3 is coming out (BOSS) and we really do no want to be stuck with an older technology that will force us to rewrite this beast of an application. WebForms hey....MS says it is an alternative to MVC - but do you ever think it will go the way of VB6 and Classical ASP? Does anyone know if WebForms has a definate life span?

Comment: Um, @jfar - get a developer to code a GridView in Web Forms, then get that same developer to code a GridView in MVC - i guarantee you it could be done in half the time with Web Forms. I agree about lack of maintanability, but im talking RAD. As for "bad coding practices" - have you every heard of the MVP pattern in Web Forms? If you do that, your code does become maintanable (and testable). Don't judge Web Forms for providing bad coding practices, blame the lazy developers. Did you by any chance downvote this answer (and the question itself)?

Comment: As for Update Panel - i agree, it's evil - but again, in some scenarios it is useful, and makes sense. And what is "MVC AJAX"?? Did you make up that term? jQuery/AJAX has no dependance on a particular server-side technology. What's stopping you from calling a web service (or a page method) in jQuery/AJAX with Web Forms. Think about what your saying before throwing about unsubstantiated sentences.

Comment: @user442003 - Microsoft have committed to providing updates to both Web Forms and MVC. They both sit on top of ASP.NET. Of course MVC is the new and exciting and best thing, but so was Web Forms when it came out. In 5 years time there will probably be a new web platform out and we will probably be complaining about MVC. Choose whatever your comfortable and skilled in. If your using Web Forms, use MVP pattern to offset the poor testability/maintainability of the common Web Forms model.

Comment: @RPM1984 - The MVP pattern forces you to write tons of boilerplate ceremony code.  You can't argue for WebForms RAD and then mention MVP.  In fact TDD and RAD don't even belong in the same sentance.  Funny that an editable GridView is the only piece of RAD WebForms that is ever mentioned in these discussions.  What else?  Add/Edit screens are time consuming and slow and GridViews only work with models of < 10 or so fields because of horizontal size issues.

Comment: @RPM1984 - And of course, you can write Javascript with WebForms you just lose a lot of capabilities because of ViewState issues.  You start modifying form fields via javascript and you'll get all sorts of ViewState was modified and can't be verified errors ( I don't remember the exact problems ).  You end up having tons of issues modifying control state without postbacks because that state is tied to the ViewData.  So yeah, you can get down to the metal with WebForms but you end up throwing away the WebForms capabilities you wanted to use in the first place.

Comment: @jfar - look, as i said in my answer - i prefer MVC for the reasons you mentioned. However i was worried this question was getting too subjective and losing track of the OP's original question. (i was reluctant to post my answer at all). Our conversation here is proof of that - we are no longer talking about the OP's problem, we're talking about Web Forms vs MVC, which is not the topic of discussion here.

Comment: @RPM1984 - I'm directly commenting about the falseness of point number 1.  WebForms is RAD only if you forgo all good practice design considerations.

Comment: @jfar - And my point #1 was directly regarding his issue of time constraints, not good practice design considerations. Anyway, we shall agree to disagree.

Comment: I have a Java background and 10 years ago we were using JSP to do exactly what MVC is doing now. For all my web projects I have always designed using layered approached ie the Business Logic layer is only ever accessed using a BL Proxy object which has its own routing. Similarly, the Data Layer is accessed via a DL Proxy object. This breaks up the design so that I can modify each layer without affect any other layer - this is not a new concept and I don't understand why ppl aren't using it more. So I will be exploiting the power of webforms, but in a modular way.

Comment: Also, server controls such as grid view with data binging breaks this modularized design so I will not be going with these controls.

Comment: @user442003 - if your not going to use those controls, then you shouldn't even bother with Web Forms - go straight to MVC. My main points as to why to use Web Forms in your scenario was speedy development *because* you could use these controls. If your going to roll your own and worried about breaking modularized design (which you didn't mention in your original question), you should be using MVC.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is completely subjective; use which ever one you want. I *personally* prefer MVC, but use which ever you want.
2. HTTP is stateless, no matter what the client or server are. That said, *all* web frameworks have tricks to make it appear stateful. MVC is *not* an exception here. It just doesn't use the same trick that ASP.NET Webforms does.
3. Yes. Detect if they have Javascript enabled, and be sure to provide alternate, server-only ways to do the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**MVC**

1. I think both are viable choices, but I would personally go with MVC, considering the MVC 3 release candidate is out now, and has some awesome new features.  I would go with MVC because it will be extremely maintainable and scaleable once the project is complete.  This sounds like it would be very helpful for you since your project *does* appear to be quite complex.  Conversely, however, it would take longer (at least from what I have experienced and read) using MVC over WebForms, so, if you feel that your team really needs to meet that deadline you mentioned, perhaps go with WebForms.
2. If you wish to proceed with MVC, its stateless nature should pose no problems to your project, at least, not that I know of.
3. Although the fact that JS may be turned off is slightly irritating to work with, WF and MVC will have to deal with issue similarly, and should have no impact on your final decision.

Answer (score -1):

go with webforms, you can always sub some of the work out to india where they have been using webforms for years, if you get speed problems then let them tackle em by playing with viewstate on component levels

though really

ultra fast asp.net by  Rick Kiessig solves 99% of all speed issues with webforms, if you have that book then webforms is a no brainer

mvc was a microsoft fork because a lot of web people could not optimise the viewstate

now you can turn off viewstate per page or per component, or just email india with code and say 'speed this up, someway'.

Comment: MVC is a design pattern, viewstate is only part of the reason someone might use MVC.  I personally use it for the ease of doing IOC and unit testing.